# Display the percentage of scroll next to the scroll bar in a UIWebView

Tags: swift, scroll, uiwebview, scrollbar

I would like to show the percentage of scroll next to the scroll bar in a UIWebView. Any idea?

Comment: Readers will be interested in seeing your code or whatever research you found when looking into this question. I imagine that the brevity of this post makes it off-topic automatically, but opinions may vary on that.

Answer (score 1):

`UIWebView` has a `scrollView` property. Set a delegate for the scroll view and implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. Based on the scroll view's contentOffset and contentSize, you can calculate the percentage.

Please note that the documentation for UIWebView states that it is obsolete and you should be using WKWebView. It also has a `scrollView` property.